# can't understand : WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION

Tags: grammar

IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR
   ANY SPECIAL, DIRECT, INDIRECT, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES
   WHATSOEVER RESULTING FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, WHETHER IN AN
   ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION, ARISING OUT OF
   OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.

It is a long sentence,let's short it as following.

THE AUTHOR SHALL NOT BE LIABLE FOR
   ANY DAMAGES WHATSOEVER RESULTING FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, 
   WHETHER IN AN
   ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION, ARISING OUT OF
   OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.

Now there are three sub-clauses here.
item1.
WHATSOEVER RESULTING FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS
It is a modifier ,to modify damage.
The damage result from lose of use,data or profits.

item2.
WHETHER IN AN
   ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION

Confused about it.

item3.
ARISING OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE
It is a modifier ,to modify damage ,same as item1.
The damages arise out of or in connection with the use or performance of this software.

My questions are:
1.My analyses for item1 and item3 right or not?
2.How to analyse item2?

Comment: **whatsoever** modifies **damages**, not **resulting**. **any damages whatsoever**, that is, damages of any kind, not only "special damages" or "direct damages" or "indirect damages" or "consequential damages".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first sight, this seems to be a legal rather than a linguistic question in that it is legal interpretation that will ultimately confirm our correct understanding of the text. It is true that there are three reduced subordinate clauses. I'll mark their beginning and end:

IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR ANY SPECIAL, DIRECT, INDIRECT, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES WHATSOEVER **(** RESULTING FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, **[** WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION **]** , **[** ARISING OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE **]** **)**.

1. Damages may result from loss of use, data or profits.
2. Loss of use, data or profits may occur in an action of contract, negligence or other tortious action.
3. Losses may arise out of or in connection with the use or performance of this software.

(1) indicates the kind of damages.

(2) indicates the legal origin of the loss.

(3) indicates the temporal circumstances in which such loss may occur.

Comment: Both `[ WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION ]` ,and  `[ ARISING OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE ] ` modify  loss ,not damage, is that so?

Comment: Both `[ WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION ]` ,and  `[ ARISING OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE ]`  are attributes of `LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS`,is that so?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature Yes, both clauses refer to "loss". As I explained, the first one describes the legal circumstances and the second one provides the temporal circumstances in which such loss can occur. The damages resulting from any such loss are thus perfectly defined.

Answer (score 0):

WHETHER *IN* AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION...

Legal actions brought against another party are said to "sound in" a particular area of law, that is, to have their basis in a particular theory of law. An action might be brought on contractual grounds, on grounds of negligence, or on some other theory of tort.

LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS

Whether you are unable to use the software because of some glitch, or you lose data because of some glitch, or you lose profits as a result of some glitch, the author of the software is held harmless.

The *arising* clause narrows the author's  freedom from liability to legal actions relating to use of the software or its performance.  The author may still be liable for other things unrelated to the software, such as spreading slanderous rumors about you or your company.